# cmd "./configure" not executing

Tags: command-line, software-installation, compiling, configure

I am trying to install gsl 2.5 on Ubuntu 18.04.
Followed the following steps:

**1.** Downloaded the latest gsl pkg from http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/gsl/.
Unzipped the tarball with archive manager, a folder named 'gsl-release-2-5' is created, opened the terminal and cd to this folder.

**2.**

```
$ cd /home
$ cd ~/gsl_pkg/gsl-release-2-5
$ sudo apt install libgsl-dev
$ ./configure
error:: bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

Received the error above.

What steps should I take now to mitigate the situation and install gsl 2.5 successfully?

---

EDIT:

Also executed the cmd :

> $ autoreconf -i -f -v

gave the reult as follows-

> autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
>
> autoreconf: running: aclocal --force
>
> autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
>
> autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Libtool

Comment: Look for and read files named README and INSTALL which may contain specific build instructions for the tarball.

Comment: @kedar your link is a 404 and isn't this in a package in the public repos ?  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gsl&searchon=names&suite=disco&section=all

Comment: @Melebius 
You are right, the file "configure" is not present in the list, instead file name "configure.ac" is present.
Thank you

Comment: @ubfan1
I read the README and INSTALL files but could not proceed after step 1. Below I am pasting the lines from the INSTALL file. Please do take a look and let me know if I am missing some vital information.

Comment: @tatsu 
Extremely apologetic for posting the wrong link.
Sincerely

Comment: You need to run `autogen.sh` to make a `configure` file. That should be works

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri 
I executed the cmd autogen.sh as :  $ ./autogen.sh  
but received an error as follows

./autogen.sh: 10: ./autogen.sh: autoreconf: not found
Now use ./configure --enable-maintainer-mode

Comment: Please what the output of `ll ~/yourFolder/gsl-release`

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri I have attached the screenshot of the same in my edit. Please have a look and let me know how to proceed further.

Comment: The autoreconfig is not found cause you don't have a build dependencies. Run `sudo apt-get install autoconf automake pkg-config libgtk-3-dev` and execute autogen.sh

Comment: Alas ! It worked.
@abu-ahmedal-khatiri 
Thank you so much for sticking around this problem with me. Thank you for giving your time and efforts.

Comment: Yo're welcome. Please check my answer section if my answered can solved your issue try to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site of ftpmirror.gnu.org/gsl your provide is eror:404 . The latest of gsl link available on https://mirror.freedif.org/GNU/gsl/gsl-latest.tar.gz and extract it.

To compile and buildin the package follow:

1. `cd ~/yourFolderOf_gsl/gsl-releaseVersions`
2. `./configure && make && make install`
3. If you have the error output that `./autogen.sh: 10: ./autogen.sh: autoreconf: not found
   Now use ./configure --enable-maintainer-mode` . You need to install a build dependencies. Run `sudo apt-get install autoconf automake pkg-config libgtk-3-dev` and execute autogen.sh
4. If that successfully, you can regenerate of configure file again using `./configure && make && make install`
5. if the gsl-config program is not on your PATH, you may need to set the GSL_CONFIG environment variable to point to it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: https://coral.ise.lehigh.edu/jild13/2016/07/11/hello/
simple steps given by Jie Liu

Comment: It's okay, if yo're not get some errors.